# How to create a trigger that wont hold the entire transaction till it complete?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

There is a procedure which have insert operation in middle for a table. The table contain a trigger and because of that the entire transaction getting hold. Is there are anyway to make trigger run on separate session and after insert operation procedure runs without waiting for the trigger to complete.

Both procedure and the trigger are

```
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Why entire transaction is getting hold because of trigger. A trigger is a event which should be doing some activity on other table. How did you identifed that because of trigger your insert is hold.

Comment: What does your trigger do? Is bypassing or delaying it an option ?

Comment: A Trigger is always part of actual DML (Insert, delete, update, etc) making any transaction related handling inside a trigger is usually a bad idea.

Comment: There is a procedure which has a part where it insert data into a table. that table has a trigger so until the trigger event completes it wait without proceeding the rest of the transaction . i know this because i keep logs in a table before and after data insert and also inside the trigger. it always "after insert" log appear after logs inside the trigger

Comment: Your pragma makes your trigger independent from your transaction. However, both transactions (yours and the trigger's) may try to write to the same records and thus hinder each other. Ideally this should never be the case; an autonomous trigger should do nothing more than write some log entries or the like. If it does more than this (i.e. write to the business tables), then the approach seems wrong.

Comment: Actually the procedure is a subscriber to oracle queue . initially it send information to a ESB. But it slows down the queue and eventually queue become offline. as a solution we planned to put data into a table and use a trigger to handle the business logic and let the subscriber end its transaction without doing heavy burden .

Comment: And the bigger problem is pragma does not do what it suppose to do and there are no related records getting manipulated by both procedure and trigger  .

Answer (score 2):

You could try runnig the trigger part as `dbms_job` ... as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myrigger
AFTER INSERT
ON mytable  
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  l_job number;
  begin 
    dbms_job.submit( l_job, 'MYPACKAGE.MYFUNCTION(''' || :new.myField || ''');' );
  END ;
/
```

Comment: So will this run separately in different session and wont effect the main transaction ?

Comment: @Optimuskck Yes it will run separetetly, as a scheduled task... note that `dms_job` will do implicit `commit` on the task that it will execute..

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes... different sesssion but not thread. If the triger execution time, lets say, is  `1 min` ... wouldn't the whole process block - even if it is executed on separate transaction? (I mean the execution remain sequencial, doesn't it?). On the other hand,  the `dbms_job` - does not block the process at all - as the scheduled procedure is executed  on different thread...

Comment: @Optimuskck as I said to the WernfriedDomscheit above, if your problem is  the excution time of the trigger - then with `dbms_job` you can tackle this issue, as the execution will be performed not only as separate transaction but also on separate thread as well.

Comment: I will use that @Plirkee and let you know.Meantime can you please tell me how to add more than one parameters in and out in the job inside itself?

Answer (score 0):

If Trigger is based on insert operation, it will hold the current session, until that trigger action is completed. This is required to maintain integrity at database side. It may be possible to design a procedure & trigger in a better way if the requirements are known.